# Images wont render after solving this error - Error serializing `.meetups[0].title` returned from `getStaticProps` in "/" `

Tags: mongodb, next.js

I had the same error as above. I found an answer here that removed the error. However, my problem now is that, nothing is being rendered on the screen for images. I am not sure where to look. Please help. There is also no error on the console. It does compile no problem.

Here's my code and a screen shot of the output.

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
    const client = await MongoClient.connect(
        'mongodb+srv://erickn:password@cluster0.66smcyq.mongodb.net/meetups?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
    );
       
    const db = client.db();

    const meetupsCollection = db.collection('meetups');
    console.log(client)
    // Fetch data from an API.

    const meetups = await meetupsCollection.find().toArray();

    client.close();

    // Always need to return an objects (props).
    return {
        props: {
            // meetups: DUMMY_MEETUPS
            // meetups: meetups
            meetups: JSON.parse (
                JSON.stringify (
                    meetups.map(m => ({
                    title: m.title,
                    address: m.address,
                    image: m.image,
                    id: m._id.toString(),
                }))
            )
        )
    },
        // Regenerate website using the updated data after deployment.
        revalidate: 1,
    };
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the issue - of course thru research as well! Here's the solution that worked for me...

```
return {
    props: {
      // meetups: DUMMY_MEETUPS
      //   meetups:
      meetups: JSON.parse(
        JSON.stringify(
          meetups.map((meetup) => ({
            title: meetup.data.title,
            address: meetup.data.address,
            image: meetup.data.image,
            // src: meetup.image,
            id: meetup._id.toString(),
          }))
        )
      ),
    },
    // Regenerate website using the updated data after deployment.
    revalidate: 1,
  };
}
```